# How do I override Emergency Bypass of a Contact or all Contacts in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, sms, phone-call, imessage

I would like to make an app that would allow the user to silence their iOS device. The Emergency Bypass setting on a Contact in iOS causes that text or call to go through even when the ring switch is set on silent and when Do Not Disturb is on. There are users like myself who have many Contacts that have Emergency Bypass set to on on our device. It takes a lot of effort to turn them all off. I also would like to turn Emergency Bypass on for many contacts at certain times, and turn them off at other times.

Comment: This is not something an app can do.

Answer (score 0):

Please, keep emergency bypass the way it is, it must be used for emergencies.

iOS already has the feature you are looking for: set your contacts to "Favorites" and then change the "Do not disturb" setting to "Allow calls from" favorites whenever you want.